# Search query dynamically created is unsafe

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection

```
// Check and set search
if($_POST['searchQuery'] !== "null"){
    $search = $_POST['searchQuery'];

    $search = explode(' ', $search);


    //long words are more than 4
$longwords = '';
$shortwords = '';


$searchCount = count($search);

foreach ($search as $word) {
    $word = trimplural($word);

    if ($searchCount > 1){

       if (strlen($word) > 3) {
           if (!in_array($word,array('sale','brand','lots'))){
                  $longwords.=' +'.$word;
                    } //check for words
        }else{ //else 3 letters
                    if (strlen($word) == 3) {
                        if (!in_array($word,array('and','the','him','her','for','new','you'))){
                               $shortwords.= " OR (fname LIKE '%$word%' OR lname LIKE '%$word%') ";
                            } //search for words
                     }//strlen == 3
        }

    }else{//else searchcount == 1
                            if (!in_array($word,array('and','the','him','her','for','new','you'))){
                               $shortwords.= " OR (fname LIKE '%$word%' OR lname LIKE '%$word%') ";
                      } 
     }


}



}else{
    $search = null;
}
```

Sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:longwords IN BOOLEAN MODE) $shortwords LIMIT " . $postnumbers . " OFFSET ".$offset;
    $q1  = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
    $q1->bindParam(':uniid', $uniid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q1->bindParam(':longwords', $longwords, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q1->execute();
```

I have a search query that is generated using the code shown above, I want to use a combined of mysql fulltext search and the LIKE query. In order to do this I have added part of the SQL query as a variable `$shortwords` to get the LIKE part to work, however, I understand that this isn't the best option because of sql injections.

How can I make this query 'safer' or sanitise the output before I implement into the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the clauses, use PDO::quote on the $word variable before adding it to the string, it will sanitize and escape the value.  Then you don't need to bindParam with shortwords, but you get the same functionality.

something like this should work:

```
if (!in_array($word,array('and','the','him','her','for','new','you'))){
    $safe = $conn->quote('%'.$word.'%');
    $shortwords.= " OR (fname LIKE $safe OR lname LIKE $safe) ";
} //search for words
```

While offset and postnumbers aren't really vulnerable to injection, it still might be nice to bind them too, which will make the query more readable, but thats just my opinion.

Also, you might want to consider defining your word list arrays outside of the foreach.  Currently the interpreter is rebuilding the arrays each iteration of the loop.  Again, not a huge deal, but worth mentioning.

Comment: thank you for your reply! unfortunately the shortwords list excludes these words from the final result, does this changes things slightly?

Comment: thanks again! are you able to provide an example of how I would use PDO::quote? and great shout I will bind the other parameters too!